# How do i auto change a cell upon entry of a another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have tried to google the answer but fail to came up with any answers other than doing VBA. I am a user who do not have any knowledge of programming

I am trying to do an excel sheet to track a person's project work

**Column A**: Project name

**Column B**: Person handling (A dropdown list could be used or a person could key their name in)

**Column C**: Status of project (Completed, Pending review, Not done)

What I hope to achieve is when a user has changed their status of the project of work to **Completed** in **Column C**, their name in **Column B** would be removed automatically

Thanks for the assistance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you want to actually change the contents of another cell (by automated means), you have to use VBA.  There are many many posts that describe this sort of thing.  Please search until you find one that has a reasonably good explanation and try to follow it (and/or adapt it, as necessary).  If you can’t get it to work, please [edit] your question to show what you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by `Scott`, Excel formulas do not DO anything TO other cells. They read them and "take" their information for their own uses, but do not do anything to them, ever. Not ever.

Excel is not like programming languages where code actively goes somewhere and at the least reads something and goes away, but very often has the need to change what it finds or change other things based upon what it finds. It just isn't and there's no way past that.

VBA (coding, just like in normal programming languages) will do so nicely, once you learn how to use it. If you know other languages already, bear in mind Excel allows macros to be written in a couple other languages as well, so you may already know how to do what you wish. And VBA has an OnChange capability that can fire when the column C cells are changed, evaluate the change, and if desired, go to the column B cell and clear its contents, so it can be completely automated for you.

If you cannot (don't know VBA or the boss won't have macros in the company spreadsheets), or do not wish to, use VBA, the closest Excel can come is using Conditional Formatting ("CF").

CF can monitor the column C cell and if its value becomes "Complete" it can apply a new format to column B:  in this case, it can change the column B font color to match the cell's background color. Usually that means change it to be white. This causes the text in the column to DISAPPEAR from sight, but NOT to be gone. It is still there, but the cell displays as empty.

If that distinctly different from actually being empty status is sufficient, then you have your solution. If it must be truly empty (for instance, for some sorting need, or maybe use of the names for some other purpose would be ruined due to the names that are not really gone), CF cannot help.

But people are not just being obtuse or preachy when they say "VBA." Excel simply flat out does not do what you need.